# When using Schedulers, System.out.println prints nothing in RxJava

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduler, rx-java

I'm fiddling around with RxJava and Schedulers. I implemented a very simple stream with a scheduler:

```
Observable.just(1, 2, 3)
      .doOnNext(v -> Thread.currentThread().getName())
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
      .subscribe(v -> System.out.println(v));
```

The example above prints **nothing** in the console.

I noticed, that when I block the main thread at the end using i.e. Thread.sleep(), System.out.println prints proper values - 1 2 3:

```
Observable.just(1, 2, 3)
        .doOnNext(v -> Thread.currentThread().getName())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .subscribe(v -> System.out.println(v));

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Can someone help me understand this behaviour?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`RXJava` uses `daemon` threads. So your app just finishes before your `Observable` starts emission. It's quite easy to check, just pass `Scheduler` which returns non `daemon` thread and you will see your output values:

```
Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.from(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(new ThreadFactory() {
    @Override public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        Thread result = new Thread(r);
        //result.setDaemon(true);
        return result;
    }
}));

Observable.just(1, 2, 3)
        .subscribeOn(scheduler)
        .subscribe(v -> print(v));
```

Uncomment the line `result.setDaemon(true);` and values will not be printed.