# Custom RxJava Observable emits nothing on subscribe

Tags: observable, rx-kotlin

I'v got this method from [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider#open-client) and it works well:

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun readTextFromUri(ctx: Context, uri: Uri): String {
    val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
    ctx.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)?.use { inputStream ->
        BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream)).use { reader ->
            var line: String? = reader.readLine()
            while (line != null) {
                stringBuilder.append("$line\n")
                line = reader.readLine()
            }
        }
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString()
}
```

Then converted it to this method that returns each line using Observable:

```
fun getUriAsStringObservable(ctx: Context, uri: Uri): Observable<String> {
    return Observable.create {
        try {
            ctx.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)?.use { inputStream ->
                BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream)).use { reader ->
                    var line: String? = reader.readLine()
                    while (line != null) {
                        it.onNext(line)
                        line = reader.readLine()
                    }
                    it.onComplete()
                }
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            it.onError(e)
        }
    }
}
```

But it didn't work as I expected, after subscribing to it nothing is printed:

```
getUriAsStringObservable(this, uri)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .doOnNext {
        print("Next: $it")
    }
    .doOnError {
        print("Error: $it")
    }
    .doOnComplete {
        print("completed")
    }
    .subscribe()
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I found three way to solve my issue:

1) Use `Thread.sleep(1)` after emitting each item.

2) Use custom scheduler which has non `deamon` thread [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35235405/3678849).

3) Use Flowable with `BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER` instead of Observable (Best way).

```
Flowable.create({
    try {
        ctx.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)?.use { inputStream ->
            BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream)).use { reader ->
                var line: String? = reader.readLine()
                while (line != null) {
                    it.onNext(line)
                    line = reader.readLine()
                }
                it.onComplete()
            }
        }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        it.onError(e)
    }
}, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
```

Thank you Javid